# Locating Button in Gridview Header

Tags: c#, css, gridview

Greetings!!
I have programmatically created a button in Gridview header and used CSS to align it to the Left corner of Gridview, but then whenever the Gridview expands the button also moves in the Gridview. Can somebody guide me on how to align the button to left and should be static even when the gridview expands? I have attached screenshots for reference. It would be grateful if anybody provides me a solution. Thanks in advance!!

Code used for creating the button:

```
 GridViewRow row=newGridViewRow(0,0,DataControlRowType.Header,DataControlRowState.Normal);
TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
            Button header_button = new Button();
            header_button.Text = "Add";
            header_button.Click += new EventHandler(this.GreetingBtn_Click);
            header_button.CssClass += "header_button";
            cell.Controls.Add(header_button);
            cell.ColumnSpan = 11;                
            row.Controls.Add(cell);
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row);
```

CSS:

```
.header_button                  
{
background-color:#007AB4;  
border-radius: 4px;
color:#FAFAFA;
font-family:Sans-Serif;
font-size:11px;
height:30px;
width:50px;
margin-bottom:auto;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the second screenshot the button has been moved when the checkbox list is added.

Comment: post your html of your button.

Comment: I created the button using C# code. However, i got the HTML for the button from Chrome.
          `<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl03$add" value="Add" disabled="disabled" id="MainContent_GridView1_add_0" class="header_button" />`